# How can I display different phrases depending on the time of day with javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, if it's between 8 and 1 pm, it would say "good morning", if it's 1:01-6:00 pm, it would say "good afternoon" and if it's between 6:01-11:59, it would say "good evening"

How do I go about doing that using javascript/jquery?

Comment: What happens between 12 and 8?

Comment: @KennyTM: it says "what are you doing up so late? Shut off your computer and get some sleep!"

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Date](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html) object:

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
if (hours >= 8 && hours < 13) {
    alert('Good Morning');
} else if (hours >= 13 && hours < 18) {
    alert('Good Afternoon');
} else if (hours > 18 && hours <= 23) {
    alert('Good Evening');
} else {
    alert('Don\'t disturb me at this lately hour');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get current hour and minute like this

```
var d = new Date();

var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
```